# Replace malloc with array

Tags: c++, canny-operator

I have an image processing program (canny-edge-detection), here is one part of the code:

```
short int **magnitude;
int rows=320, cols=240;

//Allocate memory to store the image, warning if not successful
if((*magnitude = (short *) calloc(rows*cols, sizeof(short))) == NULL){
  //some warning
}
```

I would like to use an array to avoid allocating memory dynamically, since it is not feasible at the system I'm about to run the code on. What is the size of the array in this case? I assumed

```
short int magnitude_arr[76800]
```

However the output image got cut in half.

Comment: The only thing that can be conclusively stated here is that the size of the array is most certainly 76800, or `rows*cols`.

Comment: `short int magnitude_arr[320*240];` is correct , perhaps you made a mistake elsewhere in your program

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration will give you a statically sized array with the correct size.
If you program doesn't work anymore the error is elsewhere.

If you intend to use a static size you might think about using

```
std::array<short, 76800u> magnitude;
```

or

```
std::vector<short> magnitude(rows * cols);
```

if instead rows and cols might change to make the size runtime dynamic.

In case you need a pointer to the stored data, both classes have the `data()` member functions.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do nicely.

```
const int rows=320;   
const int cols=240;
short int magnitud_arr[rows * cols];
```